# SideMenu in tableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, side-menu

is it possible to implement a SideMenu in a TableViewController? If it is possible could you describe how?

Thank you very much

Max

Comment: Do you consider SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For UIKit I recommend**:

[jonkykong/SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)

This library provides the necessary resources to use a functioning SideMenu in any ViewController

**For SwiftUI:**

In SwiftUI you can implement a Side Menu quite easily, here are some examples:

[Simple SwiftUI SideMenu](https://medium.com/better-programming/create-a-sidebar-menu-180ca218eaf2)

[More Complex SwiftUI SideMenu](https://blckbirds.com/post/side-menu-hamburger-menu-in-swiftui/)

Comment: I've used jonkykong/SideMenu, it works well!